# CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled event on change

Tags: ios

How can I monitor when `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` changed? I need something like `delegate` or `notification`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use delagte method of CLLocationManager

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

These are the CLAuthorizationStatus description in documentation:

```
    > typedef enum {
    >     kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0, // User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application
    >     kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,        // This application is not authorized to use location services.  Due
    >                                              // to active restrictions on location services, the user cannot change
    >                                              // this status, and may not have personally denied authorization
    >     kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,            // User has explicitly denied authorization for this application, or
    >                                              // location services are disabled in Settings
    >     kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized         // User has authorized this application to use location services 
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
  //Check new status
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As iOS doesn't have a native callback/notification when user change global location service settings, we cannot handle it directly. But you can club

`[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`

with

`-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
  //Check new status
}`

to achieve the desired effect like:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
 if (![ CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
  //perform action when location service is disabled
  }
}
```

Although do understand that if the permission is already denied and the location settings are changed, you wont get this callback.